# Can starship land back on earth after sending 100 tons to LEO?

Tags: spacex, spacex-starship, entry-descent-landing

Starship payload capacity to LEO is shown as 100 metric tons in [SpaceX's Page](https://www.spacex.com/vehicles/starship/). Can the starship land after sending this payload or will it require orbital refuelling to return to earth?

Related but different question : [How much fuel would the Starship need to LAND 100,000kg on Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33684/how-much-fuel-would-the-starship-need-to-land-100-000kg-on-earth)

Comment: Starship has separate header tanks for landing fuel.  They remain full until leaving orbit, so how much weight Starship carries to orbit is irrelevant.  It will have fuel for landing.

Comment: @DanHanson: It'll need a deorbit burn, though, which I believe is not intended to come from the header tanks. The header tanks are meant to be completely full (as full as physically possible given boiloff, etc.) until the landing burn, to ensure a consistent fuel supply with minimal sloshing when falling belly first and flipping around. Depending on how high your orbit is, you don't technically need a deorbit burn, because atmospheric drag will deorbit you anyway, but I wouldn't call that "landing" since you can't predict when and where you will reenter.

Answer (score 2):

Starship has not flown into orbit yet, but is expected to make its first orbital attempt in the near future. It will not need refilling before returning to Earth.